# Python web framework - other than Django

Tags: python, ajax, django, web-frameworks

Are there any other good Python web frameworks? I'm looking to try something new, I have already used Django, web.py and pylons. Also, what frameworks are AJAX-oriented or have better support for AJAX?

I'm looking for something more agile, light weight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a framework called [Pyjamas](http://pyjs.org/) which is along the lines of Google Web Toolkit which was used to build Gmail. Seems to fit the bill for your AJAX requirements.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [really long list](http://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks) of python web frameworks

Answer (score 2):

more than a framework, ToscaWidgets2 http://toscawidgets.org/documentation/tw2.core/

TW2 is a widget framework for any wsgi compliant python web framework, originally born for TurboGears, i use TW2 with Pylons, and i presume that can be used without problems with new Pyramid Web Framework (i never try to use with Django)

Now, if apart from Ajax, you like to review other Python Web Frameworks, my recomendation can be:

1) Pyramid, a evolution from repoze.bfg and Pylons, integrate great tools and developers.
2) Bootle, Flask great microframeworks for quick and dirty apps.
3) Tipfy, a web framework thinked for Google App Engine, the best for me for this (after Django)

Answer (score 1):

You might check out [web2py](http://www.web2py.com). Very easy to learn and use, and great [Ajax support](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/10) (see also, web2py [components](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/13#Components)).

Answer (score 0):

There is pylons https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48681/pros-cons-of-django-vs-pylons